# Add row by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-table, row

I have table with two buttons to add different rows and I tried this code but it doesn't work.
This is my script code:

```js
 function addRow(tableID) {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
   var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;
   for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
     var newcell = row.insertCell(i + 1);
     newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i + 1].innerHTML;
   }
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="550">
        <p><strong>Content</strong>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="50">
        <p align="center"><strong>CLO</strong>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="50">
        <p align="center"><strong>PLO</strong>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="60">
        <p align="center"><strong>Weeks</strong>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="module">
      <td colspan="4" style="width:710; background-color:#A7B8D4; color:white;">
        <p class="modulenum"><strong align="center">MODULE 1</strong>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="550">
        <p>
          <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" class="textborder" class="table" id="dataTable2" />
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="50">
        <p align="center">
          <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" class="textbordersmall" />
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="50">
        <p align="center">
          <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" class="textbordersmall" />
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="60">
        <p align="center">
          <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" class="textbordersmall" />
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border:0px;">
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Add row" onclick="addRow1('dataTable2')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="Add Module" onclick="addRow1('dataTable2')">
      </p>
      <br>
      <br>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want when user click on Add Module button it will repeat module row and increment its number. But when click on Add row button it's only repeat row with its textboxes.

Comment: It will probably not fix the issue but, you closed your table two times.

Answer (score 0):

The issues:

- The buttons were calling the wrong function name `addRow1` instead of `addRow`
- You were passing an id to the function, but the table didn't have one

I've fixed these, and tidied up the code at https://jsfiddle.net/0L4yy5rr/1/

Comment: It doesn't work probably it only increase the number without row or module

Answer (score 0):

I did this little modification to your code,, take a look, hope that helps you:

```js
function mirko(tableID){
    var table=document.getElementById(tableID)
    for(var l = 0; l < 2; l++){ 
     var cl = table.tBodies[0].rows[l].cloneNode(true)
     table.tBodies[0].appendChild( cl ) 
    }
}
```

```html
<a type="button" value="Add row" onclick="mirko('dataTable2');">Add row</a>

<table id="dataTable2">
  <thead>
   <td width="550">
    <p> <strong>Content</strong>
    </p>
   </td>
   <td width="50">
    <p align="center"> <strong>CLO</strong>
    </p>
   </td>
   <td width="50">
    <p align="center">
     <strong>PLO</strong>
    </p>
   </td>
   <td width="60">
    <p align="center">
     <strong>Weeks</strong>
    </p>
   </td>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr id="module">
   <td colspan="4" style="width:710; background-color:#A7B8D4; color:white;">
    <p class="modulenum">
     <strong align="center">MODULE 1</strong>
    </p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td valign="top" width="550">
    <p>
     <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" class="textborder" class="table" />
    </p>
   </td>
   <td width="50">
    <p align="center">
     <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255"         class="textbordersmall"/>
    </p>
   </td>
   <td width="50">
    <p align="center">
     <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255"     class="textbordersmall"/>
    </p>
   </td>
   <td width="60">
    <p align="center">
     <input type="text" value="" maxlength="255" class="textbordersmall"/>
    </p>
   </td>
  </tr>   
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Some functions work probably but i want separate two buttons one of them for adding module with increment the number of module and another one for adding row

Comment: I solved my code but there is a little problem when i delete row and then add another one it  count from beginning. you will see in my codes

Comment: can you send me the code for delete that is troubling you so I can take a look?

Comment: yes it's but there is problem in counting module number when adding row then module row

Comment: you could try to do it with for example: setting only module function to add class on that rows like this: `row1.className = 'module';` and on start of the function to count that rows only.. like this: `document.getElementsByClassName('module').length` .. I'm sorry but you are going to deep with your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem but there is another problem in counting module row when user delete module row then add another one it continues counting like user delete module 2 then add module row it must be 2 but add module 3.

```
 <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
.tf{border-bottom:0;}
</style>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
var num=1;
  function addmodule(in_tbl_name)
  {
    var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
var row1 = document.createElement("TR");
// create table cell 1
var td = document.createElement("TD")
td.setAttribute('colspan',5);
td.bgColor="#A7B8D4";
td.innerHTML = "<label style=\"width:570; background-color:#A7B8D4; color:white;\">"+"Module "+num+"</label>";
row1.appendChild(td);
// add to count variable
num = parseInt(num) + 1;
// append row to table
tbody.appendChild(row1);
  }
    var count=1;
  function addRow(in_tbl_name)
  {
var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
// create row
var row = document.createElement("TR");
var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml1 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" SIZE=\"5\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textborder\';\">";
td1.innerHTML=strHtml1 ;
var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml2 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" SIZE=\"30\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textbordersmall\';\">";
td2.innerHTML=strHtml2;
var td3 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml3 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" SIZE=\"5\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textbordersmall\';\">";
td3.innerHTML=strHtml3 ;
var td4 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml4 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" SIZE=\"5\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textbordersmall\';\">";
td4.innerHTML=strHtml4 ;
// append data to row
row.appendChild(td1);
row.appendChild(td2);
row.appendChild(td3);
row.appendChild(td4);
// add to count variable
count = parseInt(count) + 1;
// append row to table
tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
  function deleterow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if (rowCount==1) {return false;
}
else{
table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
}}
</SCRIPT> 
</head>
<body>
<TABLE ID="tbl" width="570" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="st">
<TH WIDTH="400">Content</TH><TH WIDTH="57">CLO</TH><TH WIDTH="57">PLO</TH>        <TH WIDTH="56">Week</TH>
<p align="center">
<input type="button" onClick="addmodule('tbl')" VALUE="Add Module"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="addRow('tbl')" VALUE="Add Row">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="deleterow('tbl')" VALUE="delete Row">    </p>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]