# JavaScript - Hide first element on add new row on table

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor-server-side

I have a List of Products as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-green">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Product Model</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Add Service</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Products.Any())
                {
                    @foreach (var product in Products)
                    {
                        <tr @onclick="(() => SetProductForUpdate(product))">
 

                            <td>@product.Name</td>
                            <td>@product.Name</td>
                            <td>@product.Description</td>
                            <td>@product.Price</td>
                            <td><button style="background-color:#0275d8;" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium" onclick="mirko('dataTable2');">Add</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <tr><td colspan="6"><strong>No products available</strong></td></tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

That gets the following:

[image]

if i click the Add button the selected items are added to a table with the following JavaScript function:

```
   function mirko(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID)
    for (var l = 0; l < 1; l++) {
        var cl = table.tBodies[0].rows[l].cloneNode(true)
        table.tBodies[0].appendChild(cl)
    }
}
```

And here is the table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="dataTable2" class="table table-striped table-borderless border-0 border-b-2 brc-default-l1">
                    <thead class="bg-none bgc-default-tp1">
                        <tr class="text-white">
                            <th class="opacity-2"><p class="tab">#</p></th>
                            <th><p class="tab">Name</p></th>
                            <th><p class="tab">Model</p></th>
                            <th><p class="tab">Description</p></th>
                            <th><p class="tab">Qty</p></th>
                            <th><p class="tab">Unit Price</p></th>
                            <th width="140"><p class="tab">Amount</p></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="module">
                                @*<td>1</td>*@
@*                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Name</td>
                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Model</td>
                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Description</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Price</td>
                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Price</td>*@
                               <td><p class="tab">1</p></td>
                                <td><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Name</p></td>
                                <td><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Name</p></td>
                                <td><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Description</p></td>
                                <td><p class="tab">1</p></td>
                                <td class="tab text-95"><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Price</p></td>
                                <td class="tab text-secondary-d2"><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Price</p></td>
                            </tr>           
                        </tbody>                   
                </table>
            </div>
```

which gets the following with the purpose to generate a price Quotation with the selected products

[image]

My issues as shown in the screenshot above, there is always one product empty, which is generated because of this part inside my table (Quotation template): How can i hide, or prevent that?

```
    <tbody>
                            <tr id="module">
                                @*<td>1</td>*@
@*                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Name</td>
                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Model</td>
                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Description</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Price</td>
                                <td>@UpdateProduct.Price</td>*@
                               <td><p class="tab">1</p></td>
                                <td><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Name</p></td>
                                <td><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Name</p></td>
                                <td><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Description</p></td>
                                <td><p class="tab">1</p></td>
                                <td class="tab text-95"><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Price</p></td>
                                <td class="tab text-secondary-d2"><p class="tab">@UpdateProduct.Price</p></td>
                            </tr>           
                        </tbody>
```

Comment: what does the line for (var l = 0; l < 1; l++) {  do ?

Comment: Isn't that just an infinite loop? Not sure, i have found it here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710163/18036541

Comment: no the opposite. it's going to run once.

Comment: The comment on stackoverflow suggests (var l = 0; l < 2; l++) instead (var l = 0; l < 1; l++) , but if i do that i get the row twice.

Comment: If I understand well, your issue is because you use the empty product line as a template to create the other lines that you add with Javascript. The best solution would probably to do it with c# and Blazor since it is the whole purpose of using Blazor, right? Defining a List<Quotation> that you populate when adding a product. Then in your table you simply do a @foreach() the same way you do for your product table.

Comment: Okay, Yes what i was doing here cannot work. even if i manage to display the products i cannot control the Price value. Can you please check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154494/blazor-display-selected-items-to-a-table  "Defining a List<Quotation>" you mean inside my already made for each, i should create another for each?